# Google Sheets Script Execution Time Impractically Slow

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following code linked to a button (drawn rectangle):

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Jobs');
  sheet.getActiveRange().setBackground('#ACB6FF');
```

All this does is change the background color of the selected cells, **however it takes almost 2 seconds to do it**.  Is this normal, expected behavior? Is there something I'm missing when it comes to running scripts?

Comment: Is there anything else in your function?

Comment: Nope.  That's it.

Comment: My best guess is that the delay is from the time it takes for the button to find the script and run it. If you run the script from the debugger, is it also 2 seconds?

Comment: How many cells is it updating?

Comment: Consider changing your method of access to that of a Macro - you can ditch the "button" and bind it to a keyboard shortcut, `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+{number}`: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/macros  Also, is this your only script? Or do you have libraries in your project, along with global variables? Every one of those is loaded and evaluated every time your scripts run, which can **really** add up.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple factors that could affect the execution time some of them are not on the script developer / user side.

Regarding your specific case, if your button is on the Jobs sheets replace both lines in the question by

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().setBackground('#ACB6FF');
```

This could reduce the execution time because it makes fewer Google Apps Script classes / methods calls.